# Change faster between databases in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

This simple configuration is sending me crazy.

In SSMS I'm connected on more than one database, but I can't change faster between the two of them.

So, I have something like this:

[image: Image1]

But when I wanna change:

[image: Image2]

Just the database where the query is actually running appear, master is not the name of the other database.

Comment: You could open two instances of SSMS and just alt-tab between the two.

Comment: Yes, It's a good idea. But I saw this happening, when you click on the DB list, all databases appear and it's just change between them, in the same instance of SSMS.

Comment: Just thinking...why cant you have two query windows open and use "USE databasename" at the start of the sequence?

Comment: @Chris Catignani this doesn't work... I have to change my connection in order to use another DB. Just one (the DB I'm using) appears when I write 'USE .... '

Comment: Right click on the DB..."New Query". It opens a new window with a connection.